# wicket download link clear feedback panel

Tags: wicket

I have couple of drop downdowns and a download link button. Based on the user selection, i get the file to be downloaded. if the user did not make a selection I show an error on the feedback panel. if the user then makes a selection and clicks on download link it works fine, but the previous feedback message is still visible. How do I clear it.

onclick of the download link, i tried the following, but no use

```
FeedbackMessages me = Session.get().getFeedbackMessages(); 
me.clear();
```

Comment: Can you provide some more details: Is the download link an SubmitLink? Are you using Ajax with AjaxSubmitLink? In normal case it is not necessary to clean the FeedbackMessages by your self.

Comment: It is a Ajax download link

Comment: Did you try to add the FeedbackPanel to AjaxRequestTarget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably it is

```
Session.get().cleanupFeedbackMessages()
```

even it has been changed in Wicket 6.x

Answer (score 2):

I've found this post and I think it is time to share the way for Wicket 6.x and for Wicket 7.x, because `Session.get().cleanupFeedbackMessages()` was deprecated already.

To do it for Wicket 6.x you have to implement additional filter for the feedback panel. Where to do it, it is your decision to decide.

Create a new FeedbackPanel implementation by extending from the existing `FeedBackPanel` class

```
private class MessagesFeedbackPanel extends FeedbackPanel{

  private MessageFilter filter = new MessageFilter();

  public MessagesFeedbackPanel(String id){
    super(id);
    setFilter(filter);
  }


  @Override
  protected void onBeforeRender(){
    super.onBeforeRender();
    // clear old messages
    filter.clearMessages();
  }
}
```

Provide a new Filter implementation, by implementing the existing `IFeedbackMessageFilter` interface

```
public class MessageFilter implements IFeedbackMessageFilter{

  List<FeedbackMessage> messages = new ArrayList<FeedbackMessage>();

  public void clearMessages(){
    messages.clear();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean accept(FeedbackMessage currentMessage){
    for(FeedbackMessage message: messages){
      if(message.getMessage().toString().equals(currentMessage.getMessage().toString()))
        return false;
    }
    messages.add(currentMessage);
    return true;
 }
}
```

Comment: nice job, perfect example, it works in wicket 7 as well, thanks

Comment: Thanks for the comment @MiklosKrivan

Comment: Can you tell me how to use his? I am new to Wicket and trying to remove the feedback messages. Do I add the MessagesFeedbackPanel as a component to my page? And do I still add a message by using this.info("...") ? When I do this (adding the panel as a component) the info message appears two times instead of just one ;-) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for me in Wicket 6:

```
public class MyComponent extends Panel {

    ...
    FeedbackMessages feedback = getFeedbackMessages();
    feedback.clear();
```